# Infinite Loop on setState of method passed by props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem setting state from a prop passed on to Parent component from various nested child components which causes the application to crash as a result of an infinite loop of this.setState()

Here is the innermost child component

```
SingleChoice.jsx

class SingleChoice extends Component {
        state = {
        choices: [{ name: "" }],
        questionName: "",
        type: "singleChoice"
      };

      componentDidUpdate() {
        this.props.updateState(this.state);
      }

 }
```

Called by AddQuestionOptions

```
AddQuestionOptions.jsx

class AddQuestionOptions extends Component {

  updateState = state => {
    this.props.updateState(state);
  };
  render(){
    <SingleChoice updateState={this.updateState} />
  }
}
```

Then called by QuestionOptions

```
QuestionOptions.jsx

    class QuestionOptions extends Component {
     state = {
      value: 0,
      questions: [{ name: "" }]
     };
     {...}
     updateState = state => {
        this.props.updateQuestion(state);
      };
     render(){
       return(
           <AddQuestionOptions
            updateState={this.updateState}
          />
       )
     }
   }
```

Then calling method in Parent Component...

```
SurveyForm.jsx
    class SurveyForm extends Component {
       state={
       ...,
       questions: []
       }
       updateQuestion = state => {
         const newQuestions = this.state.questions.map((question, idx) => {
           if (idx !== this.state.questions.length - 1) return question;
           return { ...question, state };
         });
         this.setState({
           questions: newQuestions
         });
      };
      render(){
         return(
             <QuestionOptions
               updateQuestion={this.updateQuestion}
         )

      }
    }
```

Comment: Post your render method as well so we can see how you are passing props

Comment: I'm not finding this very clear. I don't see an infinite loop, but I do see that in `updateQuestion` you're referencing the entire state in some of the question objects, making reference loops. If that's being exhaustively iterated at some point, that would be an infinite loop.

Comment: Code is not suficient, are you implementing any of the react lifecycle methods? as componentWillMount, componentDidMount , etc

Comment: Or maybe invoking this.props.updateQuestion on your QuestionOptions render() method??

Comment: I saw you posted your render method on SurveyForm, can you do the same with QuestionOptions?

Comment: The important thing for us to see , is how and where are you invoking this.updateQuestion on your QuestionOptions component

Comment: The real request here should be a [mcve] - make a copy of your code and start throwing way things that don't make a difference until you reach the bare minimum code that reproduces your problem. And 99.9% of the time, while making that MCVE before posting your question, you already find the problem all on your own and you don't even need to ask here anymore.